# Как работать с getch?

Tags: c++

Как составить код для очереди, чтобы при нажатии на определенные клавиши он добавлял и удалял с очереди элемент? В этом нужен `GETCH`. Просто я не знаю, как им пользоваться. Можете помочь?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int b=0;
    int c;

    c = getch();
    if (c == 'a')
    { 
        b=b+5;
    }

    cout << b << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто вызываете

```
#include <windows.h>
...
int с;
...
c = getch();
if (c == 'a') {
   например добавить что-то в очередь
```

Обратите внимание getch() возвращает **один символ**, прочитанный с клавиатуры, не дожидаясь ввода <Enter>. При нажатии <Enter> читаются подряд два символа '\r' и '\n'. Клавиша "Забой" и стрелки тоже не работают, как обычно, Вы получаете их коды.

**UPD** по поводу <Enter> ***Пардон, ошибся***

<Enter> (как на основной, так и на дополнительной клавиатуре) **выдает 1 символ** '\r' десятичный 13 (hex 0x0d).

Comment: enter означає симсол \\n

Comment: @Илья Михневич, При нажатии клавиши <Enter> она же <Return> или <ВК> функция getch() возвращает символ \\r (carrige return), а не \\n (newline) с кодом 10 (0x0a hex), которую getch() возвращает при вводе ^J (Ctrl-J).

Comment: он выдает ошибку на getch:

 `getch' undeclared (first use this function)

Comment: так вроде бы getch() в conio.h объявлен.

Comment: @navi1893, напишите какая у Вас ОС и компилятор. 

У меня  Windows 7 (в XP то же самое) MinGW gcc.exe (GCC) 3.4.5

Comment: все! сработало, спасибо! а как сделать чтобы он бесконечно добавлял элементы при нажатии, в моем случае после первого нажатия он выходит, можно такое сделать?

Comment: windows 7, на dev c++

Comment: Не совсем понял. Видимо вызывать в цикле. Кстати, закрыть поток чтения (Ctrl-Z) не получиться и Ctrl-C тоже не сработает. Работает Ctrl-Break (клавиша справа вверху с контролом). Или проверяйте прочитанные символы и например по 'q' выходите.

-

Думаю, у меня кончается лимит комментариев (это уже третий), так что отвечать смогу  только обновлением ответа (увы).

Answer (score 1):

На вопрос [[@navi1893](/users/4969/navi1893)](/users/4969/navi1893)  в комментариях

```
int b = 0;
char c;
while ((c = getch()) != 'q') if (c == 'a') b += 5;
```

Comment: вот код добавил, куда и какой код поставить чтобы при каждом нажатии "а" он добавлял туда 5 ?

Comment: Куда добавлял?

Comment: я код добавил к вопросу, посмотри так будет яснее

Comment: В соответствии с добавленным кодом.

    while ((c=getch()) != 'q') {
        if (c == 'a') {
            b += 5;
            cout << b << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");

как-то так.

Comment: спасибо большое! сработало! а как сделать так чтобы он давал числа при нажатии на клавишу по рандому? можешь помочь?

Comment: ну так пиши конкретно и четко, что ты хочешь получить

Comment: Это заморочки с буферизацией выходного потока. Напиши просто на Си.

    printf("%d\n",b); fflush(stdout); 

вместо cout << b << endl; Кстати, с обычной консолью должно работать и без fflush().

Comment: ну да, endl по умолчанию сбрасывает буфер

Comment: все, супер, работает! спасибо большое! еще можешь помочь, чтобы он при нажатии выдал числа по рандому? буду благодарен!

Comment: предлагаю это оставить ему в качестве домашнего задания. заодно пусть со случайными числами разберется. там ничего сложного нет.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand

Comment: Читай man rand, обрати внимание на srand (д.б. там же).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я ошибаюсь но разве getch(); не возвращет ANSI код клавиши ??

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/59820#60016 большой вы человек.

Comment: вот код добавил, куда и какой код поставить чтобы при каждом нажатии "а" он добавлял туда 5 ?

Comment: а что за ссылка?

Comment: @smail2133, А что такое "ANSI код клавиши" ?

Comment: тоисть еогда мы нажимаем Esc то функция возвращает 27

Comment: Да, @smail2133, именно это getch() и вернет.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017: вместо `getche()` идентично работает `_gettche()`,
а вместо `getch()` работает `_gettch()`.

Проблема `_getch()` в том, что функция вызывается дважды.